# Logging events OCaml/Async

Tags: asynchronous, logging, ocaml, ocaml-core

I've been using the global module `Log.Global` and the functions `info` and `debug` but my application is growing larger and I need more flexibility. Specifically, I'd like to be able to enable/disable events from different components of the system. I'm wondering what is considering best practice in general (I mention `Async` since it's the API I'm using but the question is more general).

It seems the API provides at least two ways to do it. There is a `?tags:(string * string) list` optional parameters. When used, it appends tags after the log message.

```
2017-08-23 17:35:38.090225+07:00 Info starting my program -- [foobar: foobar]
```

I could use that and then filter my log based on the events I want to see. How are tags used in general, are they typically literals or are there other ways of using them?

I could also use more than one logger. For instance, the functor `Make_global () : Global_intf` creates singleton. I could create one logger for each component. Is there a good reason to choose this approach? besides having different output for each log and setting the log level independently.